# how i hide the tool tip of all the button of popup in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am facing problem in hiding the tooltip of control buttons jquery popup in , i am able to hide the tooltip for close button using closeText: false , but maximizeText: false is not working.

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: i am facing problem in hiding the jquery popup control buttons tooltip

Comment: @RanjitSingh i want to hide the tooltip of the minimize & maximize button there on the popup

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ closeText: false });
  });
  </script>
<body>
 
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

Comment: use my code i have text in comment

Comment: @ManojSingh never share code in a comment. Use an answer for this

Comment: ok @NicoHaase  i  will not

Answer (score 0):

```
      try this code  

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ closeText: false });
      });
     </script>
    <body>
      <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. 
      The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
      </div>
    </body>


    See [api][1] reference

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "closeText", false );

    or

    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ closeText: false });


  [1]: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeText
```

Comment: closeText is only disabling the tooltip for close button , but i want to hide for  minimize , maximize too

Comment: it's only solving the problem for close button not the other button.

Comment: for that you should use DialogExtend  extand js library http://output.jsbin.com/ehagoy/154/

Comment: you can see code here http://jsbin.com/ehagoy/154/edit?html,css,js,output